# Clock Widget Stops Updating

Tags: android, widget

I'm attempting to create a widget that gets updated on a regular basis just as a clock widget would. The widget loads and runs without exception, but it stops updating the UI for no apparent reason. There are no exceptions thrown when I have it connected to the debugger. And there is no pattern to it. It stops at random times. It doesn't die when it loses focus (move to a different screen or a new app comes up). The widget will be running on the visible screen with the phone awake and it just stops updating.

My guess is that the OS is doing cleanup and kills the process when it needs the resources. Is there away to tell the OS to keep my process alive?

```
private PendingIntent createUpdateIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    super.onEnabled(context);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, createUpdateIntent(context));
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    super.onDisabled(context);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(createUpdateIntent(context));
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
    }
}


public static class UpdateService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startID) {
        RemoteViews updateViews = buildUpdate(this);
        ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(this, MainWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        manager.updateAppWidget(widget, updateViews);
    }

    private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) {
        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget);
        if (!EventStart.equals("")) {

            DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("M/d/yyyy h:mm a");
            endDate = fmt.parseDateTime(EventStart);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            TimeZone UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
            cal.setTimeZone(UTC);
            Date beginDate = cal.getTime();

            Date dateEnd = endDate.toDate();

            Map<TimeUnit,Long> result = computeDiff(
                    beginDate,
                    dateEnd
            );

            String Seconds = String.valueOf(result.get(TimeUnit.SECONDS));

            if (result.get(TimeUnit.DAYS) <= 0 && result.get(TimeUnit.HOURS) <= 0 && result.get(TimeUnit.MINUTES) <= 0     && result.get(TimeUnit.SECONDS) <= 0) {

                if (doVibrate) {
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    v.vibrate(1000);
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

            }
        }

        updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.info, Seconds);
        return updateViews;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've only dabbled in Android, but I think you need to build this as a service: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html --everything else can be suspended by the system at its whim.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read the post and research.

Comment: I take that back. It is running as a service. You can see in the code I have public static class UpdateService extends Service. I did have a depreciated onStart instead of onStartCommand. I'll run it a few times and see if that corrects the issue.